# how to find the lowest record in my json data and how to find total page record in my json data

Tags: java, json, restful-url

this is my controller class and my pojo class  is sampledata . i want to get the "total _page" filed and lower "id" from json data

///this is my client json data
        {"example":1,"page":1,total_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"f_name:"ss"},{"id":2,"f_name:"sss"}]}

```
    public class StudentDetailsController {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://somethinghere");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(
                    ClientResponse.class);

    if (response.hasEntity()) {
                try {
                    String message = String.valueOf(response
                            .getEntity(String.class));

                    System.out.println(message);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    System.out.println("the list -s "+gson);

                    List<sampledata> list = gson.fromJson(message,
                            new TypeToken<List<sampledata>>() {
                            }.getType());

    for (StudentDetails c : list) {

                        System.out.println("list size::::::::"  + list.size());

                        System.out.println(c.id());
                        System.out.println(c.getf_name());                  
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you De-serialize Json using a library such as Gson in your case, you can simply access the properties via the getter methods.

```
 for (StudentDetails c : list) {
     c.getTotalPage();
     c.getData().get(0).getId()
 }
```

Comment: @siva see my comment above. What do you mean by lowest. the Data array will automatically de-serialize in to a List in java and you access its elements  by index.

Comment: i mean lowest means i want to find the lowest id from that data